# Numba - how to declare signature for variable number of function arguments?

Tags: python, numba

Numba seems to support variable number of arguments in jit-ed functions:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def func(*arrays):
    return np.vstack(arrays)
```

However, I am wondering what is the correct syntax for providing the signature for this function, so that numba know which type to expect for the members of the tuple `arrays`. I couldn't find a reference to this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you should be trying to provide a type signature manually, as Numba is capable of type inference. To quote the Numba documentation on [advanced types](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/types.html#advanced-types):

> Warning
>
> The APIs documented here are not guaranteed to be stable. Unless necessary, it is recommended to let Numba infer argument types by using the signature-less variant of @jit.

To demonstrate, observe that we can compile this function in nopython mode, and Numba will build up a list of signatures as it is used:

```py
import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def func(*arrays):
    return np.vstack(arrays)


print("signatures before call", func.nopython_signatures)

arr1 = np.array([1, 2])
arr2 = np.array([3, 4])
arr3 = func(arr1, arr2)
print(arr3)

print("signatures after call", func.nopython_signatures)
```

Resulting output:

```
signatures before call []
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
signatures after call [(UniTuple(array(int64, 1d, C) x 2),) -> array(int64, 2d, C)]
```